# Fedora, terminal not recognizing command even though path variables are set up

Tags: fedora, terminal, path

I have set up path variables for the location of something called saw in a folder inside documents. When I put `echo $PATH` it shows the right path. I've exported it and put it in the bashrc file.

Path is '/Home/Documents/folder/bin'

I've made sure the path is correct, points towards the right folder.

But when I type saw into the terminal, it come up 'bash saw command not known'. Is there a way to fix this so I can use the program I want to.

Comment: Please copy and paste instead of retyping. The `bash` shell would say "bash: saw: command not found", not "bash saw command not known". Also show the output of `echo "$PATH"`, and the output of `ls -l /Home/Documents/folder/bin/saw`. Since there is something that is not the way it should be, you can not simply assert that "the path is correct" etc. Also, I have yet to see an actual Unix that has a `/Home` directory.

Comment: The path was copied directly from the files properties and gone over to make sure so mistakes or errors were included

Comment: perhaps saw doesn't have the executable permissions.  Can you run `ls -l /Home/Documents/folder/bin/saw` and report the output?